# How to consume a CDS from ABAP SQL using an association value in the WHERE condition?

Tags: abap, cds

I have a CDS view for notifications header with an association to their status

```
define view ZNOTIF as select from qmel as notif
    association [0..*] to ZNOTIF_STATUS as _status on _status.object_num = notif.objnr
{
    key notif.qmnum        as notif_id,
    notif.objnr            as object_num,
    notif.qmart            as type,
    notif.qmtxt            as description, 
    _status
}
```

Now I would like to consume this CDS in ABAP selecting all the notifications with an specific status (and without incrementing cardinality if possible).

Something like this, but of course this has a syntax error:

```
SELECT notif_id,
       type,
       description
  FROM ZNOTIF
  INTO TABLE @DATA(notifs)
  WHERE \_status-status_id = 'STATUS_FILTER_VALUE'. "Syntax error
```

Can I do that somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT notif_id,
   type,
   description
FROM ZNOTIF
WHERE \_status[ (*) ]-status_id = 'STATUS_FILTER_VALUE'
INTO TABLE @DATA(notifs).
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm. As I expected it increases the cardinality even if the association fields are not within the SELECT, but then adding DISTINCT the problem is solved.

Comment: @RaTiO you are welcome. yes, indeed.  filter on associations has to increase the cardinality