# How to get all the elements of an association?

Tags: associations, abap, cds

I have created a CDS views as follows:

```
define view YGAC_I_REQUEST_ROLE
  with parameters
    pm_req_id    : grfn_guid,
    @Consumption.defaultValue: 'ROL'
    pm_item_type : grac_prov_item_type,
    @Consumption.defaultValue: 'AP'
    pm_approval  : grac_approval_status
  as select from YGAC_I_REQ_PROVISION_ITEM as provitem

  association [1..1] to YGAC_I_ROLE as _Role on _Role.RoleId = provitem.ProvisionItemId

  association [1..*] to YGAC_I_ROLE_RS as _Relation on _Relation.RoleId1 = provitem.ProvisionItemId

{
  key ReqId,
  key ReqIdItem,
      Connector,
      ProvisionItemId,
      ActionType,
      ValidFrom,
      ValidTo,

      _Role.RoleId,
      _Role.RoleName,
      _Role.RoleType,


      _Role,
      _Relation
}
where
      ReqId             = $parameters.pm_req_id
  and ProvisionItemType = $parameters.pm_item_type
  and ApprovalStatus    = $parameters.pm_approval
```

Then I have consumed in ABAP:

```
  SELECT
    FROM ygac_i_request_role( pm_req_id = @lv_test,
                              pm_item_type = @lv_item_type,
                              pm_approval = @lv_approval
                            )
    FIELDS reqid,
           connector,
           provisionitemid
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result).
```

How to get the list of `_Relation` according to selection above.

Comment: would it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996902/how-to-consume-a-cds-from-abap-sql-using-an-association-value-in-the-where-condi/61004459#61004459

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume a CDS from ABAP SQL using an association value in the WHERE condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996902/how-to-consume-a-cds-from-abap-sql-using-an-association-value-in-the-where-condi)

Comment: @SandraRossi this question is not about WHERE clause but about the specifying association fields in the SELECT clause, so it is not actually a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not possible like in ABAP SQL queries:

```
SELECT m~*, kt~*
  FROM mara AS m
  JOIN makt AS kt
...
```

This contradicts the whole idea of CDS associations, because [they were created](https://sapyard.com/cds-part-15-associations-in-cds-views-i/) to join on-demand and to reduce redundant calls to database. Fetching all fields negates the whole idea of "lazy join".

However, there is another syntax in FROM clause which is enabled by [path expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenpath_expr_in_from_clause_abexa.htm) that allows querying underlining associations both fully and by separate elements. Here is how

```
SELECT *
  FROM ygac_i_request_role( pm_req_id = @lv_test )
       \_Role AS role
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result).
```

This fetches all the fields of `_Role` association into internal table.

**Note:** remember, it is not possible to fetch all the published associations of current view simultaneously, only one path per query.

Possible workaround is to use JOIN

```
SELECT *
  FROM ygac_i_request_role AS main
  JOIN ygac_i_request_role
       \_Role AS role
    ON main~ProvisionItemId = role~RoleId
  JOIN ygac_i_request_role
       \_Relation AS relation
    ON main~ProvisionItemId = relation~RoleId1
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_table).
```

This creates deep-structured type with dedicated structure for every join association like this:

[image]

If you are not comfortable with such structure for you task, `lt_table` should be declared statically to put up all the fields in a flat way

```
TYPES BEGIN OF ty_table.
        INCLUDE TYPE ygac_i_request_role.
        INCLUDE TYPE ygac_i_role.
        INCLUDE TYPE ygac_i_role_rs.
TYPES END OF ty_table.
```